# Count the number of multiples of $3,\,5,\,7,\,11,\,13$ in the first $1000$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I know it can perfectly be done with the inclusion-exclusion principle but I think it will be boring to count the cardinality of the intersections and because they're less than a "big" number, 1000. Is there an easier way to count them?

Comment: Seems to be $618$.

Comment: N'S John.  You are still double counting the multiples of 13,21,35 etc.  You do have to use exclusions.  It's tedious but not.  If M (n)= number of multiples =floor(1000/n) the answer is M (3)+M (5)+...-M (15) - M (21) -...+M (110)+M (165)+...  it'd be easy to program.  There might be a way to simplify.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't see the question meant different divisors

Comment: The question is ambigious.

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe... multiples of 3 that are not multiples of 5,7,11,and 13 should be floor (1000x4/5x6/7x10x1

Comment: Argh.  Stupid phone app.  So I need to think this out but 4/5 of the multiples of 3 are multiples of 7.  6/7s of those aren't factors of 7, etc.  So the answer should be floor (1000 x4x6x11x12/3x5x7x11x13) + floor (1000x6x11x12/5x7x11x13)+floor (1000x10x12/7x11x13)+floor(1000x12/11x13)+floor (1000/13).  I think that avoids double counting by not counting the multiple factors in  the first place.  We may need to play with this to make sure.

Comment: I took it to mean ciunt all the numbers between 1 to 1000 that are multiples of 3,5,7,11, or 13.  Otherwise it would be 5 separate very easy questions with utterly no worry about exclussion.

Comment: There are 333 multiples of 3.  The are 200 multiples of 5.  But 66 of these are also multiples of 3.  So there are 467 distinct multiples of 3 and/or 5.  That was my interpretation.  Otherwise there's no point.  Including no point in your pointing out they are relatively prime.

Comment: Ivm not talking about different divisors. Ivm talking about distinct multiples. The multiples of 3 and the multiples of 5 are not distinct. The 66 multiples 15 are factors of both and should not be counted twice.

Comment: I also get $618$ from a simple python script.

Answer (score 1):

There are floor(1000/3) multiples of 3.  4/5 of them are not multiples of 5.  So there are floor(floor(100/3)4/5) multiples of 3 that are not multiples of 5.  By same reasoning the are floor (12/13 floor(10/11 floor (6/7 floor (4/5 floor (1000/3))))) multiples of 3 that are not multiples of 5,7,11,or13.  Call this M3.

Likewise there are floor(12/13 floor (10/11 floor (6/7 floor (1000/5)))) multiples of 5 (some of which *are* multiples of 3 the we omitted before) that are not multiples of 7,11,13.  Call this M5.

Do the same for M7, M11,and M13.

Add these up.  This counts the multiples of lower numbers without double counting the mutual multiples of higher numbers.  Then we "catch" up the mutual multiples when we do the higher numbers.

I'm not sure how much tedium this eliviates.

Comment: So M3=191.  M5=143. M7=119. M11=83. M13= 76.  So I get 612 but the chances of my making an arithmetical error us very high.  I'm also worried there might be something wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

For reference if we have a set $P$  of primes and we want to count the
multiples of the elements  of $P$ less than some number  $N$ we get by
inclusion-exclusion for the non-multiples

$$\sum_{S\subseteq P} 
(-1)^{|S|} \bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{\prod_{p \in S} p}\bigg\rfloor.$$

Introducing $M$ as the product of the primes in $P$ this becomes

$$\sum_{d|M} \mu(d) 
\bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{d}\bigg\rfloor.$$

This because  the Moebius  function from number  theory is  the Mobius
function of the  divisor poset. Subtract these values from  $N$ to get
the number of multiples.

Doing the computation for $P=\{3,5,7,11,13\}$ and $N=1000$ we get

$$N-\sum_{S\subseteq P} 
(-1)^{|P|} \bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{\prod_{p \in S} p}\bigg\rfloor
= 618.$$

In case we are willing to accept an approximation we obtain

$$\sum_{d|M} \mu(d) 
\bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{d}\bigg\rfloor
\approx N \sum_{d|M} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}
= N \prod_{p|M} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
\\ = N \times\frac{1}{M}\times M \prod_{p|M} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
= N \frac{\varphi(M)}{M}.$$

This agrees with what we would expect from inspection and it yields
for the present problem

$$1000 - 1000 \times \frac{5760}{15015} \approx
616.3836164$$

which is an acceptable approximation.

**Remark.** Supposing that  we do not have  a set $P$ of  primes but a
set $Q$  of positive integers  which are not necessarily  co-prime the
formula becomes

$$\sum_{S\subseteq Q} 
(-1)^{|S|} \bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{\mathrm{lcm}(S)}\bigg\rfloor.$$